# Cisco VPN v5.0.01.0600 and IRE Safenet\SoftPK on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, netscreen

My work involves me to connect to two VPN's. One of them requires me to use Juniper IRE Safenet\SoftPK client and the other requires Cisco VPN Client. I have already installed Juniper IRE Safenet\SoftPK on my Windows 7 Machine and it is working fine. I have already set the two of its services SafeNet* startup property to Manual and I switch them on only when I require.

Now, when I am trying to install Cisco VPN v5.0.01.0600, I keep getting error message that I need to uninstall Juniper before installing.

My question: Is there work around way to have this installed and have both of them running on same machine?

*Cisco VPN v5.0.01.0600 Error:
Error 28000: Before Installing the Cisco Systems VPN Client 5.0.01.0600, you must uninstall the previous version of Cisco Systems Secure VPN Client or IRE Safenet\SoftPK Client, using Add/Remove Program Files option in the Control Panel. Then restart your system.*

Many Thanks,
HF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found Windows 7 and Cisco VPN 5 don't work well together to begin with. My client works with certain concentrators and others don't work at all. Apparently [a hack](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/d880dfe5-7f44-4955-8620-2a9355d8ea8b) works to fix this, but I use a different client altogether.

[Shrew Soft VPN client](http://www.shrew.net/) has worked flawlessly for me on Windows 7, and even imports Cisco VPN client profile files directly.

Comment: Shrew Soft VPN client seems like an excellent replacement for both Juniper as well as Cisco VPN. But, would using such 3rd party VPN cause any problems with Network Admins? Would they know what client I am using to connect?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. The head network admin I work with says it's never caused any problems on his end. I don't think it exports client info to the VPN concentrator either. I've tested it on an ASA 5505 and PIX 515e in my home lab and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same probleme with cisco (v4.8.01.0300) and Juniper. I've been unable to launch cisco VPN since I installed Juniper. What I did is : stop the service named "SafeNet Monitor Service" and then start the "Cisco System, Inc, VPN Service" and then I cold have launched the cisco VPN. In order to work easily with both installed, I created 2 batch files on my desktop :
- The first one to turn off the SafeNet service and then Turn on the cisco service
- The other one turn off cisco and then turn on SafeNet

MyBatchFile:
net stop "Cisco System, Inc, VPN Service"
net start "SafeNet Monitor Service"

Hope this will help

Ooly

Comment: I already tried this option and doesn't work in Windows 7 environment.